# Where is the add-ins directory

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Where can I find the add-ins directory?

PS: I want to install [this](http://codeorganizer.codeplex.com/releases/view/2126) manually, but my VS cannot load the addin after I put the addin.zip into "Documents and Settings\\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Addins"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it can read zip files at all. Have you tried unzipping it? there should be a file .addin and a .dll at least